# If value appears more than once in column, get row index for each occurrence

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this function, that will go through a table in with data starting in row 2 and going to the last row with data, in this case 12. Then I need to it check if a value assigned to variable `boardtype` appears more than once in column 1. If it does appear more than once, I need it to get the row index for each time `boardtype` is in the column 1. Then that row index will be assigned to variable `boardrow` which will change for each `boardtype` occurrence in the table. For example using the table below

| Board | Subsystem | Min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AX-11 |  | 10 |
| AX-4 |  | 10 |
| AX-6 |  | 125 |
| AX-6 | WD298588 | 40 |
| AX-6 | WD1234 | 1 |
| AX-7 |  | 125 |

If `boardtype = AX-6` then `boardrow` should be equal to 4,5,6 when looping through column 1. Then once the row index can be determined for which rows have `boardtype` value stored in it, I then need to check if variable `subsysnum` that is a string input when calling the function contains the value under subsystem column 2.

```
Function GetExternalClock(wbSearc As Workbook, boardtype As String, subsysnum As String, column As Long) As Double 
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\LookupTable.xlsx")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wbSrc.Worksheets("External Clock Freq")
    Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = ws.Columns(1)
    Dim r2 As Range: Set r2 = ws.Columns(2)
    Dim board_range As Range, firstAddress As String, subsysnum_range As Range
    FunctionName = "GetExternalClock"

    With r1
        Set board_range = r1.Find(What:=boardtype, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) ' find board type row

            If Not board_range Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = board_range.Address ' save board type address
            Else
                    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & "Board " & boardtype & " could not be found in lookup table" & vbNewLine ' if no PCB found throw error
                Exit Function
            End If
        Do While Not board_range Is Nothing ' while board type is not nothing look for value of cell in column 2
Dim boardrange_rows As Double, subnum As Double
        boardrange_rows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r1, boardtype) ' counts the number of rows that has boardtype value
        If boardrange_rows = 1 Then ' if boardtype only appears once in table
            GetExternalClock = ws.cells(board_range.row, column).value
        ElseIf boardrange_rows > 1 Then
       
Dim value_range As Long
            value_range = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            For x = 2 To value_range
                boardrow = board_range.row
'               If InStr(subsysnum, ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value) > 0 Then
'                Debug.Print ws.cells(boardrow, 2).value
                Debug.Print boardrow
                If ws.cells(boardrow, 2) Like "*" & subsysnum & "*" Then
'                If subsysnum Like "*" & ws.cells(boardrow, 2) & "*" Then
                Debug.Print "TEST2"
'                If ws.cells(value.row, 2) = subsysnum Then
                    GetExternalClock = ws.cells(boardrow, column).value
                    Debug.Print GetExternalClock
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    MsgBox "Bad"
                End If
            Next x
'            subnum = ws.cells(boardrange_rows, 2)
            
        End If
        Loop
    End With
    Exit Function
    End Function
```

Example to call the function is:

```
Dim clock As Double 
clock = GetExternalClock(wbSearch, boardtype, subsysnum, 3)
```

' clock = GetExternalClock(wbSearch, "AX-6", "WD1234TEST", 3)

Comment: Could you explain `wbSearc` since it isn't used anywhere? Is it part of an idea to pass the workbook that you are currently opening in the function? Please share an example of how you would like to call this function from a (calling) procedure e.g. `Dim ec As Double: ec = GetExternalClock(wb, "AX-6", "aaaWD1234aaa", 3)` where `wb` has already been opened in the way you did it in the function.

Comment: @VBasic2008 `wbSrc` is used to define the workbook when I set `ws`. I provided an example of how I would call the function

Comment: `wbSearch` refers to the same workbook as `wbSrc`

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup

[image]

**Result For This Screenshot**

```
AX-6          WD1234         50
```

**The Calling Procedure**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Tests the GetBoardData and GetExternalClock functions.
' Calls:        GetBoardData, GetExternalClock.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub Callem()
    
    Const SOURCE_FILE_NAME As String = "LookupTable.xlsx"
    
    ' Determine the Source path.
    Dim SourceFilePath As String
    SourceFilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\" & SOURCE_FILE_NAME
    
    ' Open the Source workbook.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SourceFilePath)
   
    ' Return the Board data in a 2D one-based array, the Board Data array.
    Dim BoardData As Variant: BoardData = GetBoardData(swb)
    
    ' Here you could already close the Source workbook.
    'swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    If IsEmpty(BoardData) Then
        MsgBox "Could not retrieve the Board data.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' The previous tasks you want to do only once, not in a loop.
    
    ' For the following, you could create a loop.
    
    Dim BoardType As String: BoardType = "AX-6"
    Dim SubSysNum As String: SubSysNum = "WD1234"
    Dim ecColumn As Long: ecColumn = 3
    
    ' Get the external clock.
    Dim Clock As Double
    Clock = GetExternalClock(BoardData, BoardType, SubSysNum, ecColumn)
    If Clock > 0 Then
        Debug.Print BoardType, SubSysNum, Clock
    Else
        Debug.Print BoardType, SubSysNum, "Not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

**The 1st Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the Board data in a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetBoardData( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook) _
As Variant
    
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "External Clock Freq"
    Const FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS As String = "A2:C2" ' adjust!?
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WORKSHEET_NAME)
    
    With ws.Range(FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' no data found
        GetBoardData = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1).Value
    End With

End Function
```

**The 2nd Function**

```vb
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Gets the External Clock from the Board Data array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetExternalClock( _
    ByVal BoardData As Variant, _
    ByVal BoardType As String, _
    ByVal SubSysNum As String, _
    ByVal ExternalClockColumn As Long) _
As Double
    
    Const BOARDTYPE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const SUBSYSNUM_COLUMN As Long = 2
    
    Dim rValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(BoardData, 1)
        rValue = CStr(BoardData(r, BOARDTYPE_COLUMN))
        If StrComp(rValue, BoardType, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' BoardType found
            rValue = CStr(BoardData(r, SUBSYSNUM_COLUMN))
            If InStr(1, rValue, SubSysNum, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' part found
                rValue = BoardData(r, ExternalClockColumn)
                If Len(CStr(rValue)) > 0 Then ' ExternalClock is not blank
                    If IsNumeric(rValue) Then ' ExternalClock is a number
                        GetExternalClock = CDbl(rValue) ' assign to result
                        Exit Function
                    'Else ' ExternalClock is not a number; do nothing
                    End If
                'Else ' ExternalClock is blank; do nothing
                End If
            'Else ' is not a part of SubSysNum; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' is not BoardType; do nothing
        End If
    Next r
    
End Function
```

Comment: For your first function `GetBoardData`  where do you loop through each row that has `AX-6` in it and get each row index? Is it in this line `Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) `

Comment: I don't. I just write all the data to an array. The other function loops through the rows (`r`) of the array and finds the data. Looping through the rows of an array is many times faster than looping through cells. Also, it's faster than using the Find method. BTW, the critical full (single) line is `Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)` which references the last non-empty cell in the columns hence `lCell`.

Comment: What does the `- .Row +1)` mean and does the `"*"` in the `.Find` line mean the last cell with anything inside it in column 1?

Comment: `.Rows.Count` means `1048576`, `.Row` means `2` for the case for `A2:C2`, in other words, I'm setting the range `A2:C1048576` where I will use the Find method to find the last cell in which ever column it is located.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate the data you listed in an array into the function I had already created for finding `boardtype` or rather is there a way to take all the cases where `AX-6` occurs and store that into an array that can be looped through?